# Unity player falls through platform/collider after using grappling hook

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

so I’m trying to make a platform game as a beginner, and one of the main mechanics is a grappling hook. Prior using the grappling hook and after finishing using the grappling hook, the player can jump around on all platforms and not fall through it. However, when I use the grappling hook, my player while grappling can just fall through the platforms. How do I fix this? (all triggers are already unchecked)

Here’s what it looks like for reference (the line is the player grappling on it and has fallen through the platform already):
[reference picture to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9GQ1.jpg)

Below is the code for my player:

```
public class Sal : MonoBehaviour{

public Rigidbody2D sal;
public float movespeed = 2f;
public float jumpspeed = 2f;
public Transform groundCheck;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public float groundCheckRadius;
public bool isTouchingGround = true;
private LineRenderer lineRend;
private DistanceJoint2D hook;

public void Start()
{
    sal = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    lineRend = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    hook = gameObject.AddComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();


    lineRend.enabled = false;
    lineRend.useWorldSpace = true;
    hook.enabled = false;

}


void Update()
{
    Movement();
    lineRend.SetPosition(0,transform.position);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
        shoot();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("space")){
        hook.connectedBody = null;
        lineRend.enabled = false;
        hook.enabled = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D ground){
    if (ground.gameObject.tag == "ground"){
        isTouchingGround = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D ground)
{
    if(ground.gameObject.tag == "ground"){
        isTouchingGround = false;
    }
}

private void Movement(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) == true && isTouchingGround){
        sal.velocity = new Vector2(sal.velocity.x, jumpspeed);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) == true){
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) == true){
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


public void shoot(){
    Vector3 shotDirection = ShootingDirection();

    int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, shotDirection, 10f, layerMask);

    if (hit.collider != null){

        hook.enabled = true;
        hook.connectedAnchor = hit.point;

        lineRend.enabled = true;
        lineRend.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
    }
    else{
        lineRend.enabled = false;
        hook.enabled = false;
    }
}


private Vector3 ShootingDirection(){
    Vector2 velocity = sal.velocity;
    Vector3 forwardDirection;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
        forwardDirection = new Vector3(velocity.x + 5f, velocity.y, 0f).normalized;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
        forwardDirection = new Vector3(velocity.x - 5f, velocity.y, 0f).normalized;
    }
    else{
        forwardDirection = new Vector3(velocity.x, velocity.y, 0f).normalized;
    }
    Vector3 upwardDirection = Vector3.up;
    Vector3 shotDirection = forwardDirection + upwardDirection;

    return shotDirection.normalized;
}
```

}

I tried editing around my code, but I don't think the problem is with the code. The problem is after a line is drawn between the grappling point and the player, Unity controls the physics of how it swings as a grappling hook, so I think it has something to do with layer/component stuff on Unity. I don't really know though, as I'm a complete beginner at this.

Comment: I'm not massively familiar with distance joints but could it be that the joint keeps you a fixed distance away from wherever its attached to? This would explain why you'd be clipping through the ground since its trying to force you to stay X units away from your grapple position